# FireBaseError: Function addDoc() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined while running react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add data to firebase database. While doing so I get this error: 'FireBaseError: Function addDoc() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined'. The registration form takes 2 inputs name and email. The function `handleSubmit` will take the inputs name and email from the form and the `addDoc` function inside it will be added to the database. the **FirebaseConfig.js** contains all the configurations of firebase.

**Registration.js**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { TextField, Button } from '@mui/material'
//import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'
import { collection, addDoc } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { app, database } from './firebaseConfig'
//import {getDatabase, set, ref } from 'firebase/database'

export default function Registration() {
    //let auth=getAuth()
    let collectionRef = collection(database, "users")
    const [data, setdata] = useState({});

    const handleInput = (event) => {
        let newInput = {[event.target.value] : event.target.value}
        setdata({...data, ...newInput});
    }

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        
        addDoc(collectionRef, {
            name: data.name,
            email: data.email
        }).then(()=>{
            alert('Data added successfully!');
        }).catch((err)=>{
            alert(err.message);
        });

    }
  return (
    <div>
        <form>
            <h1>Registration Form</h1>
            <TextField id="filled-basic" label="Name" name='name' variant="filled" onChange={(event)=>(handleInput(event))} /><br/><br/>
            <TextField id="filled-basic" label="Email" name='email' variant="filled" onChange={(event)=>(handleInput(event))}/><br/><br/>
            <Button variant='contained' color='success' onClick={(e)=>(handleSubmit(e))}>Submit</Button>
        </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**FirebaseConfig.js**

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import {getFirestore} from "firebase/firestore"
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: ...,
  authDomain: ...,
  projectId: ...,
  storageBucket: ...,
  messagingSenderId: ...,
  appId: ...,
  measurementId: ...
};

// Initialize Firebase
export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
export const database = getFirestore(app);
```

Answer (score 0):

Either name or email seems to be undefined. Try adding a condition to check that as shown below:

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
  console.log(data);
  if (data.name && data.email) {
    addDoc(collectionRef, {
      name: data.name,
      email: data.email
    }).then(() => {
      alert('Data added successfully!');
    }).catch((err) => {
      alert(err.message);
    });
  } else {
    console.log("Invalid data")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the mistake. In **Registration.js**, it should be `let newInput = {[event.target.name] : event.target.value}` instead of `let newInput = {[event.target.value] : event.target.value}`.
Thanks for reading :)